# background image is not coming from css in joomla 2.5

Tags: html, css, joomla2.5

background image is not coming from css in joomla 2.5 .
I am writing this css code for background image

```
background-image: url(images/abc-md.jpg);
```

However if i am trying on my local machine by creating a folder name website and keeping the html code and css in it ,and images are placed  in a folder named images which is also kept in  side website folder

Please help how i can make images to come from css whether inline or external  in joomla

Comment: @kenneth could you please help me out !

Comment: where is your css file located, since the url will be relative to the location of the css file, not necessarily the 'website' folder

Comment: @DavidFritsch ... after posting an answer I noticed that you had already given the solution. Sorry, I wasn't trying to jump the queue!

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling background images in your CSS, then the path to the image is relative to the CSS file, not the root of your website.

If I understand things correctly, your images and CSS directories are both at the same level inside your website folder, in which case what you want is:

```
background-image: url(../images/abc-md.jpg);
```

Note the ../ in the image path.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the style sheet you're editing is your template's? In that case, images/abc-md.jpg would be in /templates/your_template/images/ and not in the root.

To make it simple, just add / to the URL of the image:

```
background-image: url(/images/abc-md.jpg);
```

If it still doesn't work, give it a go with firebug (or chrome dev tools) and see if the rule is picked up at all (maybe you're using the wrong css selector) *and* if the image can be loaded *and* if the container size is large enough to display it *and* the possibilities are endless, why don't you try the above and let us know some more, i.e. at least your site's address ?